# Ordering of stacked bars according to variable in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to order the bars in a stacked bars plot according to the first variable "Terp" - "jars1" are ordered according to the percentage of "Terp". Any ideas how to do that? Here's the code for the plot:

```
ggplot(df) +
  aes(x = jar1, fill = factor(group2, levels=c("TERP",  "CxHy")), weight = rate) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.4), axis.text=element_text(size=7)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(days_incubated), scales = "free")
```

Here's how the data look like:

```
structure(list(group2 = c("CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", 
"CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "TERP", "TERP", "TERP", "TERP", "TERP", 
"TERP", "TERP", "TERP", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", 
"CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "TERP", "TERP", "TERP", "TERP", "TERP", 
"TERP", "TERP", "TERP"), rate = c(35.0413764604317, 1.581780096, 
48.1546154514286, 5.6177417568, 118.07707609554, 9.78168399744, 
125.236895496, 8.71879325664, 137.594582077252, 14.0889705513239, 
630.450644424867, 42.8764673332745, 752.039882591234, 23.2549865965314, 
1385.89284580167, 77.9737494781406, 0, 0, 0, 0.51091296192, 12.1578219080288, 
1.121021002368, 26.1570828734857, 0.958406204448, 311.87378680008, 
41.0741226543657, 889.66751457975, 32.9591458117879, 667.747148244659, 
26.9290441959229, 1343.81735772991, 39.2757060997948), jar1 = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", 
"3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", 
"4", "1", "2", "3", "4"), days_incubated = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'ordering according to Terp'. Do you want the bars to be reordered depending on the percentage of "Terp" in the bar?

Comment: Yes exactly @pieterbons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the outcome you're looking for? Naming of axis, variables etc not 'polished'.

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_df <- structure(list(group2 = c("CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", 
                                   "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "TERP", "TERP", "TERP", "TERP", "TERP", 
                                   "TERP", "TERP", "TERP", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", 
                                   "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "TERP", "TERP", "TERP", "TERP", "TERP", 
                                   "TERP", "TERP", "TERP"), rate = c(35.0413764604317, 1.581780096, 
                                                                     48.1546154514286, 5.6177417568, 118.07707609554, 9.78168399744, 
                                                                     125.236895496, 8.71879325664, 137.594582077252, 14.0889705513239, 
                                                                     630.450644424867, 42.8764673332745, 752.039882591234, 23.2549865965314, 
                                                                     1385.89284580167, 77.9737494781406, 0, 0, 0, 0.51091296192, 12.1578219080288, 
                                                                     1.121021002368, 26.1570828734857, 0.958406204448, 311.87378680008, 
                                                                     41.0741226543657, 889.66751457975, 32.9591458117879, 667.747148244659, 
                                                                     26.9290441959229, 1343.81735772991, 39.2757060997948), jar1 = c("1", 
                                                                                                                                     "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", 
                                                                                                                                     "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", 
                                                                                                                                     "4", "1", "2", "3", "4"), days_incubated = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -32L), class = "data.frame")


df_sum <- my_df %>% 
  group_by(jar1, group2, days_incubated) %>% 
  summarise(sum_rate=sum(rate)) %>% 
  group_by(days_incubated, jar1) %>% 
  mutate(sum_jar1=sum(sum_rate)) %>% 
  mutate(rel_jar1=sum_rate/sum_jar1) %>% 
  group_by(days_incubated, jar1) %>% 
  mutate(perc_terp=rel_jar1[group2=="TERP"]) %>% 
  mutate(group2=fct_inorder(group2) %>% fct_rev())
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'jar1', 'group2' (override with `.groups` argument)

levels(df_sum$group2)
#> [1] "TERP" "CxHy"

df_sum %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(x=tidytext::reorder_within(
    x=jar1,
    by=perc_terp,
    within=days_incubated),
    y=sum_rate,fill=group2),
    position="fill",
    stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(vars(days_incubated),
             scale="free_x")+
  tidytext::scale_x_reordered()+
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.4), axis.text=element_text(size=7))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>